# Im having trouble with this question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Find an indexed collection $\{A_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ of two distinct sets (that is, no two sets are equal) satisfying the given conditions

\begin{align*}
\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n = \{0\} && \text{and} && \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = [0,1]. 
\end{align*}

This the only problem that I am stuck, and any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it? Have you already tried something?
Hint: the left bound of the intervals should be $0$. Would it be something negative we wouldn't be able to satisfy the property of the union of the intervals. Would it be something positive we wouldn't be able to have zero be the intersection of the intervals. Can oyu take it from here?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how to do it, since my professor did not discuss this on the class. And now, I am curious what will be the answer and why is that.

Comment: Try $A_n = [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ and think about why this would work

Comment: Better to write out the problem here, than to ask users to chase it offsite. There is help with formatting math, via the Help menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\{A_n\}_{n \in \Bbb{N}} = \{A_i = [0,\frac{1}{i}] \colon i \in \Bbb{N}\}$.